# Rails current_user association by user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-api

I've got three models: user, product and order. The associations are as follows:

a User (seller) has many Products

a User (buyer) has many Orders

an Order has one Product

an Order has one User (buyer)

a Product has one User (seller)

a Product has one Order

Now in the product model there's an association to a user:

```
belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "seller_id"
```

in the products_controller for adding a new product linking it to a user:

```
def create
  @product = current_user.products.create(product_params)
  ....
```

In the database the foreign key has also been renamed to "seller_id". 
When the current_user.products line is called the response fails

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'user_id' for Product.):
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

I'm not sure how to change the current_user to products association to use this seller_id key. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:foreign_key` option you have in your `Product.belongs_to` actually needs to be over on `User.has_many`, ie., in `User`:

```
has_many :products, foreign_key: :seller_id
```